# Add extra key in laravel eloquent result

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a laravel query builder result that looks like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "awardID": 2,
      "title": "Dummy title",
      "status": "active",
      "raceStart":"",
      "raceEnd:":""
    }
  ]
}
```

What i want to output is something like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "awardID": 2,
      "title": "Dummy title",
      "status": "active",
      "period": {
        "raceStart":"",
        "raceEnd:":""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This would have been much easier if the period was a table with a 1 to 1 relationship with parent table but this is not the case here.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to get the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if this will work. I haven't tried though but according to documentation we can add accessor and mutators. But it will change every response you are doing with the model.

### **Using Eloquent**

```
// Your Model
class Race extends Model
{
    {...}
    protected $appends = ['period'];
    // accessor
    public function getPeriodAttribute($value)
    {  
        $this->attributes['period'] = (object)[];
        $this->attributes['period']['raceStart'] = $this->attributes['raceStart'];
        $this->attributes['period']['raceEnd'] = $this->attributes['raceEnd'];
        unset($this->attributes['raceStart']); = $value;
        unset($this->attributes['raceEnd']);
        return $this->attributes['period'];
    }
}
```

Now when you will access `$race->period` will give the `raceStart` and `raceEnd` value.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

else another option is after query, do a `map`

```
{...}
->map(function($data) {
    $data->period = (object)[];
    $data->period['raceStart'] = $data->raceStart;
    $data->period['raceEnd'] = $data->raceEnd;
    unset($data->raceStart);
    unset($data->raceEnd);
    return $data;
});
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#introduction

### **Using QueryBuilder**

```
$races = DB::table('races')->get();

$races = array_map(function ($data) {
    $data->period = (object)[
        "raceStart" => $data->raceStart,
        "raceEnd" => $data->raceEnd
    ];
    unset($data->raceStart);
    unset($data->raceEnd);
    return $data;
}, $races->data);
```

Comment: the documentation is a little vague on how method 2 works. Am using the query builder and not eloquent. nothing seems to work

Comment: Then propably you can use `array_map` or `array_walk` in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: I have added example for implementation. Welcome.